# Visual Studio Git branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I am new to GIT and GIT in VS, and struggling to create branch that will be visible to others.

What have I tried:

1. Created local branch from remote/master as specified [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/branches)
2. Right click on branch shows **disabled option "Publish branch"**
3. Everything I commit and sync is **visible on master branch** to other developers (but they don't see my new branch). This is especially annoying.

Please help me on how to create branch that will be visible to others and more important how to commit and sync changes to that branch only and master. Basically I expect to reproduce branches with the same behavior as in TFS source control (not GIT)

I am using: Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition with Visual Studio Team Services (was VS Online) git repository

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish the branch on remote `origin`, you have to push the branch **not on** master. To do that, check in the push windows the destination branch on the remote, and set the name of your branch.

It seems that by default, your mentioned branch is pushed to master.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, please elaborate on this or rephrase, I don't understand following: "check in the push windows the destination branch on the remote".

Comment: I don't know git on visual studio but you should be able to choose the destination branch while publishing your code. Could you work with command line ? If true, you can do `git push origin local_branch` to publish/push your local branch onto the remote.